# Regex for fetching nouns in text

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I'm facing some problems with Regular expressions in python. 
I have a text of Pos tagged words in the following format

```
('play', 'NN')|('2', 'CD')|('dvd', 'NN')|('2', 'CD')|('for', 'IN')|('instance', 'NN')|('i', 'PRP')|('made', 'VBD')|('several', 'JJ')|('back', 'NN')|('ups', 'NNS')|('of', 'IN')|('my', 'PRP$')|('dvd', 'NN')|('movies', 'NNS')|('using', 'VBG')|('dvd', 'NN')|('r', 'NN')|('w', 'NN')|('and', 'CC')|('r', 'NN')|('w', 'NN')|('and', 'CC')|('it', 'PRP')|('plays', 'VBZ')|('the', 'DT')|('dvds', 'NNS')
```

What I wish to do is extract all the nouns from this text and all the nouns appearing together(with no words present between them) should be in the same string. All the tags that start with NN are the noun words. Here is the regular expression i wrote for this:

```
re.compile(r"(\|?\([\'|\"][\w]+[\'|\"]\, \'NN\w?\'\)\|?)+")
```

I'm new to writing regular expression so sorry for the messy expression, but here's the ouptput it generates:

```
["('play', 'NN')|", "|('dvd', 'NN')|", "|('instance', 'NN')|", "('ups', 'NNS')|", "('movies', 'NNS')|", "('w', 'NN')|", "('w', 'NN')|"]
```

What I want is for words like 'back ups' and 'dvd movies' in the corpus i.e. nouns appearing together should appear together in the output.

What am i doing wrong, can anyone please sujjest!

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse nouns. Regular Expressions are not suited to this task as they cannot understand the semantics or grammar of a given language. Please consider using something like nltk.

Comment: @JamesMills -- I believe that OP already has the words tagged as nouns in the tokenized grammer syntax...  e.g. the second element in the pseudotuple is 'NN'

Comment: I'd still use nltk here regardless, even if to identify which of the positionally tagged tokens are in fact nouns.

Comment: @JamesMills -- I have used nltk to generate the above text. What i actually wish to do is extract the nouns out of the text of words! I cannot use nltk pos tagger to check for nouns every time because it takes a lot of time to execute. I have generated a file with all the words tagged and I am doing further processing on that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using regex? Isn't it just parsing text that you want?

Updated thanks to mgilson's comment

```
import ast
nouns = []
for word_and_tag in pos_tagged_words.split("|"):
    word, tag = ast.literal_eval(word_and_tag)
    if tag.startswith("NN"):
        #do something?
        #probably this...
        nouns.append(word)

#use nouns
```

Comment: `word, tag = ast.literal_eval(word_and_tag)` might do trick :-) -- Then maybe an `itertools.groupby` with `lambda t: t[1].startswith('NN')` ...

Comment: I did not want to split the words on the basis of "|" because then i would have to separately check for nouns appearing together and join them. I was hoping regex would do this job for me. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do something pretty cool with itertools here.  Assuming you can reliably split the words on `|`:

```
def word_yielder(word_str):
    tuples = (ast.literal_eval(t) for t in word_str.split('|'))
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(tuples, key=lambda t: t[1].startswith('NN')):
        if key:  # Have a group of nouns, join them together.
            yield (' '.join(t[0] for t in group), 'NN')
        else:  # Have a group of non-nouns
            for t in group:  # python3.x -- yield from :-)
                yield t
```

Comment: Your code is working but its generating all the words instead of just nouns. But the main task I wanted to do(join nouns) is happening. 
I don't know much about itertools either so i guess i'll look into it. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2732789 -- If that's the case, just cut off the `else` statement ... Then you'll only have the nouns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pyparsing solution:

```
from pyparsing import *

LPAR,RPAR,COMMA,VERT,QUOT = map(Suppress,"(),|'")
nountype = Combine(QUOT + "NN" + Optional(Word(alphas)) + QUOT)

nounspec = LPAR + quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes) + COMMA + nountype + RPAR

# match all nounspec's that have one or more separated by '|'s
noungroup = delimitedList(nounspec, delim=VERT)

# join the nouns, and return a new tuple when a nounspec list is found
noungroup.setParseAction(lambda tokens: (' '.join(tokens[0::2]), tokens[1]) )

# parse sample text
sample = """('play', 'NN')|('2', 'CD')|('dvd', 'NN')|('2', 'CD')|('for', 'IN')|('instance', 'NN')|('i', 'PRP')|('made', 'VBD')|('several', 'JJ')|('back', 'NN')|('ups', 'NNS')|('of', 'IN')|('my', 'PRP$')|('dvd', 'NN')|('movies', 'NNS')|('using', 'VBG')|('dvd', 'NN')|('r', 'NN')|('w', 'NN')|('and', 'CC')|('r', 'NN')|('w', 'NN')|('and', 'CC')|('it', 'PRP')|('plays', 'VBZ')|('the', 'DT')|('dvds', 'NNS')"""
print sum(noungroup.searchString(sample)).asList()
```

Prints:

```
[('play', 'NN'), ('dvd', 'NN'), ('instance', 'NN'), ('back ups', 'NN'), ('dvd movies', 'NN'), ('dvd r w', 'NN'), ('r w', 'NN'), ('dvds', 'NNS')]
```